# Celery periodic tasks not running when root logger is configured to use raven

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, sentry, raven

I'm using **Django** with **Celery** in order to execute periodic tasks and **Raven** as a sentry client.

So far I've managed to run several apps with celery beat and all worked fine.

For some reason, In a recent app I'm working on, when I'm settings the root logger to use a **'sentry'** hander, the periodic tasks are not running.

When settings the root logger to only use **'console'** handler, it does work.

I can't wrap my head around what causing this issue.

This is my logging dict:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'root': {
    'level': os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL','INFO'),
    'handlers': ['console'],
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'raven': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['console','sentry'],
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'celery': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

}

And the env var controlling the root logger handlers:

```
    ENABLE_SENTRY = os.environ.get('ENABLE_SENTRY', 'FALSE') == 'TRUE'
    if (ENABLE_SENTRY):
        LOGGING['root']['handlers'] = ['console','sentry']
```

Note: Seems like the root logger doesn't log to console after that change

This is how I run the celery beat and worker:

> python manage.py celery worker -E -B --maxtasksperchild=1000
>   --concurrency=10 --loglevel=DEBUG -Ofair

This is part of the packages I'm using:

> celery==3.1.17  django-celery==3.1.16 raven==5.0.0 Django==1.8.7

This is my celery.py file:

```
"""
This module will hold celery configuration
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.conf import settings
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',     'ltg_backend_app.settings')

# init the celery app
app = Celery('ltg_backend_app')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you change ['handlers']['sentry']['level'] to the same thing as the console handler and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Tried it. Didn't help.

Comment: try this option: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-hijack-root-logger

Answer (score 1):

did you configure raven to trap the necessary signals needed in order to work with Celery? here's how i configure my Celery app:

```
import celery
from django.conf import settings

import raven
from raven.contrib.celery import register_signal, register_logger_signal


class Celery(celery.Celery):
    def on_configure(self):
        #
        # https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/celery/
        #
        if 'dsn' in settings.RAVEN_CONFIG and settings.RAVEN_CONFIG['dsn']:
            client = raven.Client(settings.RAVEN_CONFIG['dsn'])
        else:
            client = raven.Client()  # should do nothing

        # register a custom filter to filter out duplicate logs
        register_logger_signal(client)

        # hook into the Celery error handler
        register_signal(client)

app = Celery('foobar')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

see here for more config options and details: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/celery/